# Not able to Create the HttpServletRequest object in Rest assure for test case

Tags: java, spring, servlets, rest-assured

I am writing the test case for a java application that uses a method like `refreshAndGetAuthenticationToken` (`HttpServletRequest` request). So, I tried to create test cases for this method but since the `HttpServletRequest` is an interface I am not able to create an object for it. I also tried with `mockito` but passing the request with json format is not supported rest Assure.
test case is

```
@Test
    public final void testRefreshAndGetAuthenticationToken() {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();        
        String token = given().contentType("application/json").body(authenticationRequest).when().post("/auth").
                then().statusCode(200).extract().path("token");

        // MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
         HttpServletRequest mockRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
         mockRequest.setAttribute("Authorization", token);
         Mockito.when(mockRequest.getHeader(tokenHeader)).thenReturn(token);

         given().contentType("application/json").header("request",mockRequest).when().get("/refresh").then().statusCode(200);

    }
```

Comment: Please add some code, it will be more usefull..

Comment: added the test case

Comment: If you are in an intgration test you can inject directly your HttpServletRequest in your test case.

Comment: it is not the integration test.....unit test case

Comment: What about using Spring MockMvc class?

Comment: problem was resolved by just passing the header parameters,atomatically it will set into the httpServletRequest object